# make a navbar that continue an image

Tags: css

I am trying to get this result: a header that "continues" from the logo in it.
I have tried the solution of the image aligned to a container, or to put a long image as a background but I am not satisfied with either method.
Is there any way to get a good and stable result on all screens?
I am not putting code as I have only made two fairly simple attempts, and I have no idea what to write.
Thank you very much to anyone who can spare a minute!
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTBLD.png)
[Current situation on two different desktop resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggXhd.png)

Comment: Just an advice, some times designs aren't implementation friendly and may not give good feedback or the amount of time consumption to achieve the design isn't worth its returns. That's why a good designer do beautiful designs that are easily implementable. In your case, the design should be redesigned, it would be less time consuming and more profitable. In case you want to implement your design, for starters, your image should be an svg, then you would adjust the image to align with navbar, then you would need to make sure that is responsive which is hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS positioning and negative margins as shown.

**Html**

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**Css**

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 80px; /* adjust as needed */
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -20px; /* adjust as needed */
  z-index: 2;
}

.logo img {
  display: block;
  height: 100px; /* adjust as needed */
}

nav {
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
}
```

> the logo is positioned absolutely to the top left of the header, with a negative margin to overlap with the rest of the header. The rest of the header content is positioned relatively with a higher z-index than the logo, so it appears on top of the logo

hope this helps

Comment: Hi Sam! Thank you very much, I was already working on a similar path and you gave me a couple of great tips!
Thanks again for your very helpful post, I will gladly buy you a coffee if you have a profile!
Have a great day!

Comment: You can vote as an answer